# create a payment method token in braintree paypal "vault" only flow?

Tags: paypal, braintree

The braintree docs for the server-side :https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/paypal/server-side/java
only covers the "checkout" and "checkout with vault" flow, not the vault flow.

What I want to know is if I am not charging the customer, only want the customer to agree to the billing agreement then store the payment method token for future payments,
What is the proper way to do that?

My search led me to two possible answers:

1. Create a customer (with the nonce) then extract the payment method token from it. https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/customers/java#create-with-payment-method

```
  .firstName("Fred")
  .lastName("Jones")
  .paymentMethodNonce(nonceFromTheClient);

Result<Customer> result = gateway.customer().create(request);

result.isSuccess();
// true

Customer customer = result.getTarget();
customer.getId();
// e.g. 160923

customer.getPaymentMethods().get(0).getToken();
// e.g. f28w  here I got the payment method token which I can store on my end
```

2. Create the Payment method directly, but still need to pass in a customerId

https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/payment-methods/java

```
PaymentMethodRequest request = new PaymentMethodRequest()
  .customerId("131866") // I don't need customerID, can I just put some dummy value?
  .paymentMethodNonce(nonceFromTheClient);

Result<? extends PaymentMethod> result = gateway.paymentMethod().create(request);
```

Am I on the right track? Which is the correct way to do it? (If it is a new customer and I don't care about the customer ID?)

Thanks!